# Nested rules in QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, style, visualisation, rule-based

I work with QGIS 2.18. I have a polygon shapefile with two atrributes: id (unique for each polygon) and type.

I visualize the shapefile using the "type" attribute, but I would like to add a nested rule or category using the "id". When I try to do that, for each type, all the available ids are added when, what I want is to add only the ids that correspond to the type I am modifying.

For example, if I have

```
"id" "type"   
  0  forest
  1  road
  2  road
  3  river
  4  forest
  5  building
  6  river
```

I would like to have:

- One category for 'forest' with the nested values of "id" 0 and 4
- One category for 'road' with the nested values of "id" 1 and 2
- One category for 'river' with the nested values of "id" 3 and 6
- One category for 'building' with the nested values of "id" 5

For 6 features it is simple, but I have 200 hundreds of them.

The goal is to keep the visualization by type and to be able to hide/show the features that I am interested in.

I know I can use the filter option, but when the filter is active I loose the ability to edit the file. I could also split the file using the "type attribute" but I would like to avoid doing that and to keep everything in one file.

Is there a way to do that?

edit Jan 2023

the answer I posted was done using QGIS 3

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, three years later, I found what I was looking for.
I never thought entering a formula in the category value.
When defining the nested categories, instead of entering the attribute, I would enter something like

```
if("type" = 'forest',"id",NULL)
```

then I only get nested the id values that are defined for the type forest and all the other go the category null that I can easily remove

Answer (score 0):

Go to layer > properties > style

Choose Categorized as styling-preference

[image]

Now set column to 'type' and click Classify.

[image]

Every single category will show up.

If you just want to visualise one category-type at a time, you can uncheck the others in the legend of the TOC.

Comment: I think with this approach there will be a border (of course based on visualization techniques) between features of the same class that probably does not give a nice view. I assume the `"Dissolve"` algorithm might be applied first and then `"Categorized"`-style

Comment: @Taras, if it is needed, you can disable the border style in the styling manager...

Comment: @PieterB. Thank you but I don't see how your answer answers to the question. You are describing a categorized visualization which is very straightforward. I am asking for a nested visualization where for each category I can have listed all the corresponding features and where I can hide/show each feature individually without losing my type visualization.

Comment: do you just want to viualise one category-type at a time?  You can uncheck the others in the TOC

Comment: @PieterB I would like to be able to uncheck each feature separately without losing the visualization by category, that is why I am asking for nested options

Comment: I think this is not possible.  However, there is a function 'is_selected()' that can help you.  If you select those features you want in the attributetable, only those will show up in the main window.  If you are interested in that, I can adapt my answer

Comment: Coming back to this question some years later. Sorry @PieterB for not answering your last comment. No it was not was I was looking for and I understand it is not possible...but since then, we are now able to edit a layer even a filer is applied on it, so this would be a turnaround.